# Extracting spectral signatures from ROI using ENVI5.3

Tags: remote-sensing, envi, multi-band

I used ENVI's Band Math functionality for calculating a certain index to find out the dominance of a mineral. The output is one monochrome band as seen below, I really need your help to learn how to extract the spectral signatures of the bright areas?

[image]

Comment: Does this help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ukrgGUkxJlU ? Can't test myself, since I don't have access to ENVI currently.

Comment: The video you recommended and the whole playlist is really helpful. However, what I'm looking for is to learn how to get the spectral profile of the bright areas seen above base on the wavelength in the x-axis.